# Using React-Native Expo in Github Actions without committing 'env' js file

Tags: react-native, build, environment-variables, apk, expo

I'm trying to achieve building an APK for each time there's a push to master.
But I'm using an 'env' file and Expo needs it to build the APK (importing it in some places in the code).
I don't wish to commit the 'env' file, and trying to avoid it.

Is there any workaround or do I have to commit the 'env' file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
I found a solution. I kept the entire file as a Github Secret and then added a script to create the env file from the secret.

```
- name: Create env.js file
uses: actions/github-script@0.9.0
with:
  script: |
    const fs = require('fs');
    if (!fs.existsSync('env.js')) {
      fs.writeFileSync('env.js', process.env.ENV_FILE);
    }
env:
  ENV_FILE: ${{ secrets.ENV_FILE }}
```